# Is there any real documentation or code examples on how to use the expect4j library?

Tags: java, tcl, expect

The documentation on the google code project page is pretty thin. I'm wondering if there is any in depth documentation on using [expect4j](http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/); code examples would be helpful as well.

Comment: Added link; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I found some examples here:

http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/test/java/expect4j%3Fstate%3Dclosed

Usually with very small libraries like this don't expect walls of documentation